# Confusing interchangeability of 汝 and 己

Tags: kanji, pronouns, archaic-language, first-person-pronouns, second-person-pronouns

In most cases, 汝 is the formal/archaic second person pronoun, "you/thou", and 己 is a humble and archaic first-person pronoun or a way to refer to oneself.

However, confusingly, in many dictionaries, both the first-person pronoun and second-person pronoun are listed as definitions of 汝 and 己, and some compounds using these two kanji actually list them interchanged with each other as variant forms.

> [汝等]{うぬら}
> Pronoun
>
> 1. ye; you. ​Archaism, Derogatory, usu. plural
> 2. me; I; us; we. ​Archaism, Only applies to わいら
>
> **Other forms
> 己等 【うぬら】、汝等 【わいら】、汝等 【なむだち】、汝等 【なむたち】**

> [己]{な} Pronoun
>
> 1. I​. Archaism
> 2. you.​
>
> **Other forms 汝 【な】**

Why have 汝 and 己 become associated with *both* "I" and "you"? In Chinese, 己 is associated solely with the self and 汝 is associated solely with "you".

In what cases would 汝 be used as "I" and 己 used as "you"? [汝]{うぬ} and [汝等]{わいら} seem to be the only readings of 汝 that mean "I", while the standard reading of [汝]{なんじ} only means "you/thou". However, the standard reading of [己]{おのれ} can mean both "I/self" and "you". If it was in a text, how would you be able to tell which it refers to?

Comment: i’ve often wondered the same thing. but keep in mind that no one really has a problem understanding “見る.” where the subject and object could be in principle just about anything. but context gives it away. i tend to think of words like 己 as a placeholder in the sentence and not think of it too literally. japanese however is not alone in having the same word embodying apparently contradictory meanings. this came up a lot in sanskrit texts i studied too.

Comment: Are you talking about the word or kanji? Kanji is just neat mnemonics for a word, and when the reading is not immediately clear, it is usually reduced to kana.